# User control page with application bar windows phone

Tags: user-controls, popup, windows-phone, application-bar

I am creating an app that has multiple pages, and one of them is a user control page, which works like a pop up of a paranoma page. 
How can I add an application bar on that user control page???
I have been trying to use the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
>     <phone:ApplicationBar>
>             <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
>                 <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
>                 <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
>                 <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
>                     <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
>                     <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
>                 </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
>         </shell:ApplicationBar>
>         </phone:ApplicationBar>
```

and I get an error message saying 'The tag 'ApplicationBar' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone'.'.

I welcome any ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:
      You define it in the app resources zone:

```
<Application.Resources>

    <shell:ApplicationBar x:Key="GlobalAppBar" IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1" Click="Button1_Click" />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2" Click="Button2_Click" />
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1" Click="MenuItem1_Click" />
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2" Click="MenuItem2_Click" />
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>

</Application.Resources>
```

See more here : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394043(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394043%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)